# How to Run COSMOS OS in VB 2010

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, operating-system, cosmos

I'm trying to build a OS COSMOS in (Visual C# Express 2010, Sorry I type VB Out of habit) I have the VB 2010 COSMOS files not the VB 2008 ones when I press debug it says it is a Class Library. I'm quite new to COSMOS i've had the VB 2008 version before and when I pressed debug it came up with QEMU, Virtualbox , and ISO (And more but those are the three I used), So how do I run my os?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Forgot, Just made the Edit

Comment: I'm not very familiar with your problem. But in visual studio you can try to set different startup project - and may be some else will start your virtual os.

Answer (score 1):

If your still wondering after 5 years 3 months.

you can't really. unless you spend ages on old cosmos builds but it's just easier getting the 2018 version of cosmos on Visual Studio 2017. in 7-8 years of them coding cosmos, it will be more efficient using the latest build of Visual Studio and Cosmos. But if your used to the old one, then I'm not stopping you from using it. But i'm just suggesting to get the latest one and keep on seeing the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Also from my last answer, vb.net isn't supported as well as c#. It's best to use c# as one of the creators said to me that VB.net isn't supported that much compared to c#.

Also c# is like the same as vb but just with ; at the end and with { } and more brackets.

The link to the conversation is here: [github #964](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/issues/964)

Last Answer:

If your still wondering after 5 years 3 months.

you can't really. unless you spend ages on old cosmos builds but it's just easier getting the 2018 version of cosmos on Visual Studio 2017. in 7-8 years of them coding cosmos, it will be more efficient using the latest build of Visual Studio and Cosmos. But if your used to the old one, then I'm not stopping you from using it. But i'm just suggesting to get the latest one and keep on seeing the latest updates.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, Cosmos won't properly install the VMware player. You can try installing it from [the VMware website directly](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/7_0).